# How come the C1 is above the ring in fructose-6-phosphate and C1 is below the ring in fructose-1,6-bisphosphate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality

Does the phosphofructokinase-1 flip the position of the covalent bonds? If I've understood correctly, C2 is a chiral atom, so it would make a difference if C1 goes from above the C2 to below the C2.

[image: Drawing of fructose-6-phosphate converted to fructose-1,6-bisphosphate]

Comment: A picture would help.

Answer (score 1):

In the cell, both the phosphate and the bis-phosphate occur predominantly in the beta form. As hemi-ketals, both rings can open and isomerize. This changes the stereochemistry of C2, the anomeric carbon. However, enzymes might be specific for one or the other form (in the case, they would react with that form, and more of that form would be made through isomerization of the other, non-substrate anomer).

For the E. coli phophofructokinase-2 enzyme, crystal structures of both substrate ([3uqd](http://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/3uqd)) and product ([3n1c](http://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/3n1c)) are available. In both models, the sugars are in the beta anomeric form.

According to wikipedia, this is the beta form of fructofuranose:

[image]

Again according to wikipedia, this is the beta form of fructofuranose 6-phosphate (but comparing it to the non-phosphorylated form, it is not):

[image]

Finally, again according to wikipedia, this is the beta form of fructofuranose 1,6-bisphospate:

[image]

So there is a name/structure mismatch for the middle structure, which might have propagated through the internet.